# shallow and deep cloning in C# .net

Tags: c#

```
class CloneExample : ICloneable
{
    private int m_data ;
    private double m_data2 ;

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public CloneExample()
    {

    }

    public CloneExample(int data1, int data2)
    {
        m_data = data1;
        m_data2 = data2;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return String.Format("[d1,d2] {0} {1}", m_data, m_data2);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CloneExample aEx = new CloneExample(10,20);
        CloneExample aEx2 = (CloneExample)aEx.Clone();

        Console.WriteLine("the first object value is {0}", aEx.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("the first object value is {0}", aEx2.ToString());

        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

1. I wrote a exmaple to understand how shallow cloning works.In the above example in the 
   clone method I am calling this.MemberWiseClone() , since in the class I have not implemented the memeberwiseclone . who will provide the default implementation?

Comment: The implementor? Not quite understanding the question. Are you asking how MemberwiseClone is implemented?

Comment: @Jodrell, surely the implementor will define the explicit implementation rather than the default implementation ;)

Comment: MS advise avoiding implementing this interface, there are several pages in 'Framework Design Guidelines' about this, the reason being it does not explicitly define methods for a deep or shallow clone...

Comment: I wanted to know how MemberwiseClone is implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Memberwiseclone** first create instance probably using **Activator.CreateInstance** which then iterates over all the fields within the type and set the value to the corresponding member/field.

But I would rather not use ICloneable at all. If I needed to use Cloning I use BinaryFormatter to serialize an object graph then deserialize it so that I would get new **deeply cloned** instance.

Comment: I agree with Int3. There is no reason ever for implementing `ICloneable`. The Designer of the .NET Framework made a mistake. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/03/125427.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Every object inherits from "Object", even if you didn't specify.
So it's [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx).

Comment: but how the base class(system.object) will know the data memebers of the derived class.

Comment: The method is implemented by the framework and could do all sorts of "behind the scenes" work. For instance: using reflection you could get at all sorts of details, including private members.

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of `MemberwiseClone` comes from the [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) class in .NET.

The [MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57ctke0a.aspx) method uses reflection to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

That's provided by the base Object class. Check the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx).